# Two states sharing data issue in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.js and I have two states within a component. Each state sets its own data through two separate functions to render the modals data to the input form. These two modals are created through two different files.

The issue is when one modal renders data to its state, the other state will have that data even though they use two separate states. How do I get each state to only render its own data?

Not showing the full code block, just the essentials:

```
Constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      platInput: [],
      platInput2: [],
    };
    this.onSelection = this.onSelection.bind(this);
    this.onSelection2 = this.onSelection2.bind(this);
  }

  onSelection(value) {
    this.setState({ platInput: value });
  }

  onSelection2(value) {
    this.setState({ platInput2: value });
  }
.
.
.
render() {
    const { platInput, platInput2 } = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
      <div className="form-row">
       <div className="form-group col-md-10">
        <TextareaAutosize
          type="text"
          disabled
          className="form-control"
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          value={platInput}
          id="target_state"
         />
      </div>
      <div className="float-right">
       <DirectionModal
         id="addTargetStateBTN"
         onSelection={(e) => {
         this.onSelection(e);
         console.log("inside of e", e);
         }}
        />
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div className="form-row">
       <div className="form-group col-md-10">
        <TextareaAutosize
          type="text"
          disabled
          className="form-control"
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          value={platInput2}
          id="target_state"
         />
      </div>
      <div className="float-right">
       <AspirationalModal
         id="addTargetStateBTN"
         onSelection={(e) => {
         this.onSelection2(e2);
         console.log("inside of e2", e2);
         }}
        />
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

ScreenShots:

[image: When you select data from DirectionModal]

[image: When you select data from DirectionModal]

[image: When you select data from AspirationalModal]

[image: When you select data from AspirationalModal]

[image: Console logs]

Comment: I see a mistake here. `(e) => { this.onSelection2(e2);}` what is this `e2` refers to ? I guess it should be  `(e2) => { this.onSelection2(e2);}`

Comment: I can't really see what the problem is here. You have two of everything - handlers, text areas, modals and state values - it's not obvious how there could be a collision. Perhaps if you can add a simplified codesandbox which demonstrates the issue (or create an [inline React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/12799351), although that can be fiddly) then it will be easier to see what's not working.

Comment: I provided screenshot of the application in use

Comment: For the e2 situation, it was a misspell on the question code it should be (e2) => onSelection2(e2)